# Display the Attribute Values

Tags: xml, xslt

I would like to use XSLT to display all the attributes of the XML snippet below. However none of my `id` attribures are appearing.

**XML:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<courses> 
        <course instructors="e101 e102 e103 e104" name="EWS.NET"/> 
        <course instructors="e101 e102 e105" name="GWS.NET"/> 
    <employees> 
        <employee id='e101' name="Aaron Skonnard"/> 
        <employee id='e102' name="Simon Horrell"/> 
        <employee id='e103' name="Dan Sullivan"/> 
        <employee id='e104' name="Scott Bloom"/> 
        <employee id='e105' name="Bob Beauchemin"/> 
    </employees> 
</courses>
```

**XSLT:**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="html" encoding="utf-8"/>
<xsl:template match="/">
<h2>Courses and Instructors</h2>
</xsl:template>
<xsl:template match="employees">
<xsl:for-each select="employee">
<xsl:value-of select="employee/@id" />
</xsl:for-each>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Can someone help me understand why the `id` attributes are not being displayed with my XSLT code?

Comment: you should add `<xsl:apply-templates/>` to your first template. To your for-each loop, you must have `<xsl:value-of select="@id"/>`. You are already in the node `employee`, all you have to do is select the attribute value. Otherwise, your above template would select `<employee><employee id="XXXX"></employee></employee>`, which is not present in your input XML.

Comment: Hi Joel, Thank you very much!  Your direction is very clear.  I see it now why it didn't work, before.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try the template below:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output method="html" encoding="utf-8"/>
    <xsl:template match="/">
        <h2>Courses and Instructors</h2>
        <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="employees">
        <xsl:for-each select="employee">
            <xsl:value-of select="@id" />
        </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```